# How to make this query return result for a specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm

I have a query which goes like this :-

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM pg_attribute, pg_type WHERE attrelid = typrelid and typname = 'table_name' and attname in ('column1','column2','column3','column4')
```

I'm trying to get the value of the column 'count' this way (after I execute the query of course):-

```
$columnExist->getInt('count')
```

The problem here is I'm getting 'Invalid resultset column: count'. I'm not sure what is the problem here, anyone can help me out. The query works with this though :-

```
$columnExist->next() //returns 4
```

Comment: Is the problem that count is a reserved word? Try `SELECT count(*) AS c ...` and `$columnExist->getInt('c')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. A stupid mistake. Should execute in this order :-

```
$columnExist->next();
$columnExist->getInt('count')
```